# Is there a way to increase by 1 each of the numbers following the "sum:" value in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: numbers, sublimetext3, increment

Is there a way to increase by 1 each of the numbers following the "sum:" value in Sublime Text 3?
Most importantly, this is not necessary in the entire text, but only from a certain point. Prior to this, the lines from sum:1 to sum:509 should remain untouched, that is, it is necessary that only the selected cursor be counted.

From this:

```
sum:510
abcd11
sum:512
efjh22
sum:518
ijkl33
sum:529
mnop44
```

It should turn out like this:

```
sum:511
abcd11
sum:513
efjh22
sum:519
ijkl33
sum:530
mnop44
```

I tried the "Increment Selection" package, but I didn't find how to add the "sum:" value as a starting point... And it seems like I can't increase all numbers by 1 with it.

Comment: The linked duplicate question shows how to use the internal `Arithmetic` command to perform the operation that you want. For your case, you would select the numbers by using multiple cursors (e..g. select the text `sum:` on the line you want to start with, then press `ctrl+d` until the rest are selected, and move the cursors over